# How big were the shooting models used in the original Thunderbirds TV show?

Tags: tv, production, thunderbirds

This is from a production perspective of the 1964-1966 Thunderbirds TV series.

The various Thunderbirds vehicles appear in numerous shots including bay scenes as their pilots are transferred aboard before launch (or where the appropriate pod is selected for TB#2), as well as sequences in various phases - launch, enroute, landing (or docking, in the case of TB#3 with TB#5).

Because of film-making demands, one might imagine that each vehicle was built at more than one scale - large for close-up shots, smaller where movement is required (or for relative scale as TB#4 launched from its TB#2 pod or the bottom of TB#3 as the crew boards via the couch). I'm interested in the number of models of each Thunderbird craft and the sizes made/used for filming.

I'm also curious about the size of the sliding pool which formed the roof aperture for TB#1's launch silo.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsfNRYbcld4 - Some model shots here

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaQ0R3uNhFI - Some model shots here

Comment: Wikipedia lists quite a few stats (FAB1 was the largest model at 7ft, all Thunderbirds except 5 was built in 3 or 4 scales, the largest scale model of Thunderbird 3 was 6' tall) and they're all referenced, but sadly I don't own any of the books!

Comment: See https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/The_Models_of_Thunderbird_1 and related pages.

Comment: @DoscoJones https://thunderbirds.fandom.com/wiki/Behind_the_Scenes_(Classic_Thunderbirds) has some pictures which really give a sense of the size(s) of the models, which closes in on an answer to my question.